# Hive - Replace columns in ORC table

Tags: hadoop, hive, alter-table, orc, hive-serde

I have a hive table saved in ORC files, this is the definition in the "create" command:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
```

I want to drop a column from the end, so I tried the "Alter Table - Replace Columns" command, where I didn't write the column name - but got this error:
`FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Replacing columns cannot drop columns for table default.table. SerDe may be incompatible`

Is there a way to replace columns in a ORC table in Hive?
Google failed me on this subject....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the hive tutorial,REPLACE COLUMNS command can be done only for tables with a native SerDe (DynamicSerDe, MetadataTypedColumnsetSerDe, LazySimpleSerDe and ColumnarSerDe).

So for your case, 
create a new table with required column. 
insert into new table from old table .
Rename old table to someother table.
Rename new table to old table.

Thanks.